# "Server is Not Operational" when attempting to change password

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I use LDAP to validate the user/pass, no problem.  When I change the password I get "server is not operational"

When I put an invalid user name the UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity it returns null, but when I use a correct userName it throws the error.

my Code:

```
        public static string ChangePassword(string adminUser, string adminPassword,
        string domain, string container, string userName, string newPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            PrincipalContext principalContext =
                new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, container,
                    adminUser, adminPassword);
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName);
            if (user == null) return "User Not Found In This Domain";

            user.SetPassword(newPassword);
            return user.Name;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Have any configuration in server needed?

Comment: Is the server clustered?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158099/why-does-authenticating-against-ldap-with-directoryentry-intermittently-throw-co

Comment: @Chris Lively thanks, but is a single server of test with 2012 server standard Evaluation

Comment: Have you tried accessing it using the IP address instead of the DNS name? (trying to eliminate DNS issues)

Comment: Are you changing the admin password in your tests?

Comment: I create a new user for test... Try Administrator too, but nothing

Comment: If I send wrong UserName, not get error, just return null, only error when correct UserName

Comment: @ Chris Lively Is not DNS too... I Put wrong pass to admin and return logon failure;;; :(

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608971/net-4-5-bug-in-userprincipal-findbyidentity-system-directoryservices-accountma?rq=1  They indicate problems in .net 4.5

Comment: I Pass to 4.0 and nothing again... I Think is a server configuration...